# Constant in Orthogonal trajectory?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to find an orthogonal trajectory but I am rather confused why do we eliminate the constant in the process of finding it.

Answer (score 0):

We eliminate all the ARBITRARY constants (you would not try to eliminate 5 if it were there) to form the general differential equation which encodes in itself all the members of the family of curves which you may have gotten from varying the arbitrary constants.
You then solve the differential equation for the orthogonal trajectory and will get a family of curves (with the same number of arbitrary constants). 
Any curve gotten from the family so obtained will (iff they meet) meet orthogonally any curve of the initial family.